# how to configure service and repository classes spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface FileRepository { }


public class FileRepositoryImpl implements FileRepository {}
```

Service and Impl:

```
@Service
public interface FileService { }


public class FileService implements FileService {

@Autowired 
FileReposiory repo;

}
```

TasK:

```
@Component
public class DummyTask  {

    @Autowired
    private FileService fileService;



    public void run(String schedule) {
        fileService.runtask(schedule);
    }
}
```

I am trying to run a simple application using the annotations above. This application has no REST endpoint or use a controller. My `fileService` has `null` reference when executing `DummyTask`.

Also, when I am running the Junit test to test the `FileRepository`, I also get `fileRepository` as null. Could someone please point out how it is unsatisfied and how to correct?

```
public class FileRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private FileRepository fileRepository;


    @Test
    public void testGetCustomerDir() {

       //blah    
    }
}
```

I Execute my task as follows:

```
 threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(new Job(reportSchedule), new CronTrigger(reportSchedule.getCronExpression()));

   class Job implements Runnable {
        private String schedule;

        public Job (String schedule) {
            this.schedule = schedule;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
           reportExportSchedulerTask.run(schedule);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DummyTask needs to be a Spring bean itself in order for Spring to autowire beans in it for you. You can fix this by marking it as a @Component:

```
@Component
public class DummyTask implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    private FileService fileService;


    @Override
    public void run() {
        fileService.runtask(blah);
    }
}
```

As for the tests, you should mark it as a @SpringBootTest. This will make the beans available to the test to be autowired.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FileRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private FileRepository fileRepository;


    @Test
    public void testGetCustomerDir() {

       //blah    
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I updated `DummyTask` which has a member `ReportScheduler` which I initialise when scheduling. I get `Parameter 0 of constructor in DummyTask required a bean of type ReportSchedule that could not be found`. Can you update your answer ?

Comment: Now that DummyTask is a bean you need to let Spring instatiate it for you and so you shouldn't have a custom constructor. You can fix this by also marking ReportSchedule as a @Component

Comment: I made `DummyTask` a Component now, with autowire `FileService` but getting `Field fileService in class required of a bean of type FileService could not be found. ` updated above the code

Comment: You should put the @Service annotation on the class not the interface